# How to keep persistent routes with split tunnel VPN?

Tags: macos, catalina, vpn

I am using an IPSec VPN on macOS Catalina to connect to my remote office.  I want to send only one subnet through this VPN and all other traffic through the local router.  I know how to set this up, after connecting the VPN I run these commands:

```
sudo route change default 192.168.4.100
sudo route add 192.168.1.0/24 -interface ppp0
```

But this resets every time I reconnect the VPN.  How can I configure macOS to do this automatically every time I connect the VPN?